# AppEngine + DataNucleus RDBMS + JPA 2 project throws exception when using @OneToMany annotation

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, jpa, datanucleus

Entity classes were created in Eclipse using the JPA wizard from an existing MySQL database, but had to remove the @OneToMany annotations because these errors pop up during enhancement (using DataNucleus Enhancer version 3.1.1).

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected exception
    at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhancer.execute(Enhancer.java:76)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhance.<init>(Enhance.java:71)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhance.main(Enhance.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhancer.execute(Enhancer.java:74)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 40
Exception Details:
  Location:
    cultivartehidroponia/Order.getOrderItems()Ljava/util/List; @4: ifnull
  Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2ab4 004a c600 242a b400 4a2a 07b9 006f
    0000010: 0300 9a00 162a b400 4a2a 072a b601 0db9
    0000020: 0098 0400 c001 0fb0 2ab6 0056 9900 2e2a
    0000030: b400 5a05 32c0 005c 07b6 0079 9a00 1e2a
    0000040: b400 5a06 32c0 005c 07b6 0079 9a00 0ebb
    0000050: 007b 5913 0111 b700 80bf 2ab6 010d b0  

    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1855)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.annotations.AbstractAnnotationReader.getJavaBeanAccessorAnnotationsForClass(AbstractAnnotationReader.java:310)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.annotations.AbstractAnnotationReader.getMetaDataForClass(AbstractAnnotationReader.java:146)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.annotations.AnnotationManagerImpl.getMetaDataForClass(AnnotationManagerImpl.java:171)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.loadAnnotationsForClass(MetaDataManager.java:2650)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.loadClasses(MetaDataManager.java:496)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.getFileMetadataForInput(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:734)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.enhance(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:525)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.main(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:1258)
    ... 7 more
```

I can use the entities fine, just without the mapped-by fields.

To bypass this issue, I had to temporarily implement this functionality using transient fields, such as:

```
@Transient private List<ViewProduct> products;
```

and simulate the @OneToMany feature manually as:

```
public List<ViewProduct> getProducts() {
    EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction trans = em.getTransaction();
    try {
        trans.begin();
        this.products = em.createNamedQuery("ViewProduct.findByProductTemplate", ViewProduct.class).setParameter("prodTemplateId", this.getProdTemplateId()).getResultList();
        trans.commit();
    }...
```

But this defeats the purpose of having that nice feature... ;(
Maybe a configuration issue? But why does everything else work and not this?
Anyone out there with similar errors? Any recommendations?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

DataNucleus v3.1 is not supported/developed, and hasn't been for some time. You should use v3.2+, which has at least one fix to JDK 1.7 enhancement.

Comment: And are you actually using "datanucleus-appengine" to persist to GAE/Datastore ? because if you aren't then delete it. If you are then you have the option of grabbing SVN for that plugin https://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/  and building it, and that would work with DN 3.2/3.3. Why Google are too lazy to release the latest code for their plugin I've no idea.

Comment: FYI if using "datanucleus-appengine", there is a built v3.0.0 of it (built from their SVN, and works alongside DN3.2/3.3 jars) in the DN maven repo at http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2/

Comment: No idea about GAE (config/deploy), I don't use it, and the plugin is Google's. It passes all tests when run local and no reason to think it wouldn't when deployed (since all previous 1.x, 2.x do too). Suggest you get onto Google's group and hope some Google person answers. But then you don't say what is wrong when you use that 3.0 jar (with DN3.2+ jars)

Comment: I was finally able to compile project with the new DN jars. It required _javax.persistence-2.1.0.jar_ in classpath. So everything compiles now, but keep getting the same error (just a bit of a different bytecode) when I uncomment the `@OneToMany` annotations! `DataNucleus Enhancer (version 3.2.5) for API "JDO" using JRE "1.7"
Encountered a problem: Unexpected exception
Please see the logs [C:\...\Temp\enhance3080440938724960447.log] for further information.` I'm going nuts with this! I love DN and can't wait to make it work, but it seems like this isn't happening to anyone else! What gives?

Comment: Looking back through the original stack trace (new one not posted) you seem to get this when running the enhancer not after it, so that maybe suggests the problem is before then ... creating compiled classes with JDK1.6? and then running them in a JDK1.7 env (i.e the enhancer)? See also http://java.dzone.com/articles/javalangverifyerror-expecting   otherwise you reduce it to a small standalone testcase that is runnable elsewhere. The DN enhancer, when run under JDK1.7 expects stackmap frames in bytecode (i.e JDK1.7 compiled)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but the vm flag does not make any difference and the App Engine no longer supports Java 6, so I'm screwed, it looks like. For what is worth, here are the contents of eclipse.ini: `-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/javaw.exe 
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
`

Comment: the bug/problem is in whatever created that class file in the first place ... eclipse compiler? if its oracle JDK that created it then that should be reproduceable outside Eclipse (e.g in Maven).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse and Google plug-in, you may need to upgrade the IDE.  I was using Indigo with 1.9.4 and I have similar issues with the enhancer.  Problem is gone after I switched to Kepler with the associated Google plug-in, etc.